# How often will the temporary app data store be deleted?

Tags: windows-runtime

I've read the documentation about application data (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx), but I have a question about the temporary data store :

I understand that its content may be deleted very often (maybe every time the app is launched) if the user starts the disk cleanup, or if the disk is full.

But if the hard drive has enough free space, will the content be deleted or not ? Does the maintenance task keep deleting the files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation it is specified that this is *data that could be removed by the system at any time.* so I would assume that my files will not be deleted if there is an active open handle on them, but other than that I think it is not safe to assume any particular non documented behaviour. I would expect temporary files to be removed more frequently on tablet devices or phones, for example.

Comment: Ok, I will assume the data can be deleted every time the app is launched, as nothing more is documented.